# WhereHas on a polymorphic relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I have the following table:

```
table logs
| id | loggable_id | loggable_type | action |
```

loggable_type could be `Contract`, `User` or `Card`
I need to get ALL records from the `logs` table, but I have to run `whereHas` on each of the loggable_types, so something like that:

```
$logs = Log::whereHas('contract', function() {

})
->whereHas('user', function() {
})
->whereHas('card', function() {
});
```

But I'm not sure how to define each of those relationships. Right now I only have:

```
   public function loggable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
```

It's Laravel 5.6 if it matters.

Comment: Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-polymorphic-relationships.

Comment: `whereHasMorph()` is triggering Laravel's default behavior and looging for `has_morph` column, hence throwing a `column not found `has_morph`

Comment: Oops, I mixed the projects... this one is 5.6 :( Going to update it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
Comment::whereHasMorph('loggable', [User::class, Card::class], function ($query) {
    $query->where('title', 'foo');
})->get();
```

Comment: `whereHasMorph()` is triggering Laravel's default behavior and looking for a `has_morph` column, hence throwing a `column not found has_morph`. Maybe it doesn't work  in 5.6?